# How to run GNAT Programming Studio on Raspberry PI 3 (Raspbian)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ada, gnat-gps

I can not run GNAT Programming Studio on Raspberry PI 3 (Raspbian).

I am using `2017-06-21-raspbian-jessie.img` and `gnat-gpl-2016-raspberrypi-linux-linux-bin.tar.gz`

After unzipping and typing in terminal `sudo ./doinstall` it is installed in `/usr/gnat`. Then I get a message saying

```
GNAT GPL is now installed. To luanch it, you must put /usr/gnat/bin in front of your PATH enviroment variable.
```

Then I type in terminal `PATH="/usr/gnat/bin:$PATH"; export PATH`.

Then I type in terminal `gps` after that I get

```
/usr/gnat/bin/gps_exe: 1: /usr/gnat/bin/gps_exe: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I have tried executing executable in `/usr/gnat/bin` but then I get

```
/usr/gnat/bin/gps_exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

How to install it properly and be able to run it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install it on an x86 computer.

From the README:

> - The GNAT GPL compiler for raspberrypi is a cross compiler, hosted on
>     linux-x86 (or linux-x86_64)

Comment: It is possible to run GNAT Programming Studio with `sudo apt install gnat-gps` on Raspberry PI 3 but that is a old version.